# Copy all products and category tree to a different Magento installation

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have a magento store and in effect, I am cloning the whole site in terms of its catalog. This includes products, categories, images and product detail.

However, I am a bit stumped on how best to do this. I have 221 categories, 8000 products etc. I was thinking of cloning the website, however, I do not want the theme, orders, customers, cms pages etc. Just the products and the images.

I have taken a look in phpmyadmin to see if I can find what I can do in there, maybe export out the products and their categories, and then import this into the SQL of the new site. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a look in the product import/export that are in place in Magento.

You should be able to work with the export from your current shop to include products, categories, images and then using the file import into your new shop. It should all be possible via the admin section of the Magento shops.

The other option that might work for you could be [MageFlow](https://mageflow.com/) which allows users to share information between sites.

Comment: But the import/export of data does not solve creating the category tree within the new Magento